# How to download from requester payer aws s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I go about downloading from this s3 bucket:

aws s3 cp --request-payer requester s3://adatascientist/parler/v1/post.ndjson.zip

I am not very technically minded, do I need a particular software or programme to do this? I have already created my AWS account I am just not sure on the next steps.

The website is here for any extra information: https://parler.adatascienti.st/research

Comment: you will have to issues this command while being logged into your AWS account. With that the data transfer costs out of AWS will be charged to your account.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have installed the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), then:

- Use `aws configure` and provide your Access Key and Secret Key
- Use `aws s3 cp --request-payer requester s3://adatascientist/parler/v1/post.ndjson.zip .` to copy the file to the current local directory

There is no Data Transfer charge if you do this from an Amazon EC2 instance in the same Region. If you download to your own computer, you will be charged for Data Transfer (9c/GB).